# AngularJs project doesnt run in ie-8 and onward?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please help how to run angularjs project in ie-8 and onward?

we have venueSvc angular service that are working fine in other browsers(chrome,firefox,opera etc) but not working in ie-8 and onward.

it is giving the following error.

Unknown provider: venueSvcProvider <- venueSvc

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your service is not being included properly. Ie8 has some issues with directives being used as elements without being specified, however it should work in general. That error looks as though the program cannot find the provider, so make sure it exists in your source.